# How to colorize output of git?

Tags: bash, colors, git

Is there a way to color output for git (or any command)?

Consider:

```
baller@Laptop:~/rails/spunky-monkey$ git status
# On branch new-message-types
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   app/models/message_type.rb
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
baller@Laptop:~/rails/spunky-monkey$ git add app/models
```

And

```
baller@Laptop:~/rails/spunky-monkey$ git status
# On branch new-message-types
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   app/models/message_type.rb
#
```

The output looks the same, but the information is totally different: the file has gone from unstaged to staged for commit.

Is there a way to colorize the output? For example, files that are unstaged are red, staged are green?

Or even `Changes not staged for commit:` to red and `# Changes to be committed:` to green?

Working in Ubuntu.

EDIT: Googling found this answer which works great: `git config --global --add color.ui true`.

However, is there any more general solution for adding color to a command output?

Comment: You want something that colorizes all command outputs? How would it know which parts to color?

Comment: I guess if there was a way to configure it using regex: Each color could have a start regex. And there could be a default color regex to turn off all colors. And, if text "foo" appears, display it in a certain color...

Answer (score 344, accepted):

You can create a section `[color]` in your `~/.gitconfig` with e.g. the following content

```
[color]
  diff = auto
  status = auto
  branch = auto
  interactive = auto
  ui = true
  pager = true
```

You can also fine control what you want to have coloured in what way, e.g.

```
[color "status"]
  added = green
  changed = red bold
  untracked = magenta bold

[color "branch"]
  remote = yellow
```

I hope this gets you started. And of course, you need a terminal which supports colour.

Also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44297/64235) for a way to add colorization directly from the command line.

Comment: I think it might be worth putting git config --global color.ui auto (@Evgeny 's answer) at the top of yours...I think that's likely to be what most people are looking for.  I've upvoted both...I'm just saying, for the sake of the internet as it comes here, I think a lot of people just want that simple one liner.  All the better if they get it, plus your extra goodness.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - in the `[color "status"]` section I added `branch = yellow`.

Comment: you can add [color] section to project's .git/config file too

Comment: And you can just set a configuration variable for a single invocation of a git command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18304605/134044

Comment: @msouth putting `git config --global color.ui auto` on top of this answer actually produces error `fatal: bad config line 1 in file ~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: Hi @nougako, I apologize, I don't think what I said was as clear as it could have been.  I meant that this stackexchange answer should be edited to add the command `git config --global color.ui auto` to the beginning _of the answer_.  It doesn't work to add the command to the config, as you correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 294):

You probably want to use

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

The `auto` part says that git will only try and use color on terminals that support it, and you will not get ANSI sequences if you redirect output of git commands to a file for example. Setting it to `true` is same as `auto`, and this is also the default since Git 1.8.4.

The `color.ui` is a meta configuration that includes all the various `color.*` configurations available with git commands.

This is explained in-depth in `git help config`.

When `color.ui` is set to `always` it will always emit ANSI color characters, even when piping the output like `git log | less` while when set to `auto` it will not print colors unless the output is to the terminal.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between color.ui `true` (which `auto` points to) versus `always`? I read [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorui) but I still don’t get the difference.

Comment: @chharvey `color.ui = auto` + `git diff | less` - no colors, `color.ui = always` + `git diff | less` - colored output. `LESS=-R` is implied.

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer gives the most common solution.
If for any reason you need not to permanently change the configuration, which that solution does, you may override the configuration for a single git command:

```
git -c color.ui=always <usual git command and options>
```

For example:

```
git -c color.ui=always status
git -c color.ui=always diff
```

Tested: supported on git 2.4.6, *not* supported on git 1.7.1.

Comment: For anyone else trying to get color when piping into `less` like I just was, you can make `less` pass the color escape characters through to the terminal via `less -R`.

Comment: When was this feature added?

Comment: And for completeness: if you pipe it to `less` and forget to use `-R` on the command line, you can interactively type `-R` at it to switch that mode on. :)

Answer (score 25):

```
git config --global color.ui auto
git config --global color.branch auto
git config --global color.status auto
```

Comment: FYI, Only this worked for git version 1.5.2.1, others answers didn't.

Answer (score 18):

```
git config --global color.ui always
git config --global color.branch always
git config --global color.diff always
git config --global color.interactive always
git config --global color.status always
git config --global color.grep always
git config --global color.pager true
git config --global color.decorate always
git config --global color.showbranch always
```

Answer (score 4):

or turn off all/most of the colorization off via:

```
git config --global color.ui false
git config --global color.branch false
git config --global color.diff false
git config --global color.interactive false
git config --global color.status false
git config --global color.grep false
git config --global color.pager false
git config --global color.decorate false
git config --global color.showbranch false
```

Comment: OP wasn't looking to turn _off_ colors, rather to turn _on_ colors. In the OP he stated how to do in for `git` and wants some way of doing it in a more global sense. If you know of such a method, please edit your answer to explain that.

Comment: sometimes people are looking for something closely related but slightly different - but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I liked it @theRiley

Answer (score 3):

For a colored `git diff` piped into `less`, this works:

```
git -c color.diff=always diff [...] | less -R
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Arbitrary Command Output Colourer](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/acoc.shtml). It mostly works, but I haven't figured out how to work around a bug where prompts expecting input aren't shown and you can't simply type the known needed input and press enter to continue in every case.

Example of `~/.acoc.conf` for `git`:

```
# git
[git/ae]
/.*(error:.*)/                                    red+bold
/.*(warning:.*)/                                  yellow
/.*(hint:.*)/                                     magenta
/.*(up-to-date).*/                                green+bold
/.*(nothing to commit).*/                         green
/^(\+.*)/                                         green
/^(-.*)/                                          red
```

..which works nicely along with `alias git="acoc git"` in `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is four years old but no one responded from my camp, the color blind. If you can distinguish colors, ignore my post.

"git status" for example puts out text that is white on background/black on white background (legible), dark gray for deleted (illegible against a black background but legible against a white background) and medium gray for added (barley legible on black background, illegible on white background). I used to toggle the background of my terminal window to/from white/black so I could read the illegible text. A simple solution is more:

```
 git status | more
```

This makes all the text legible on a standard white or black background terminal window.

Comment: You can also change the config to set everything to no color by default (`color.ui = never`).

Comment: Brilliant use of piping to get readable colors.

Answer (score 1):

To colorize the output of `git diff` you can add a color.diff section to    ~/.gitconfig. For example:

```
[color "diff"]
  new = bold italic 154
  old = bold italic 196
```

Here `154` and `196` are ANSI 256-color codes. For more details see `man git config`.

Answer (score 1):

Some minimalist OSes popular for creating docker containers, like Alpine, may come with stripped down versions of `lesss` that do not output in color. Install the `less` package with `apk add less` command in Alpine.

Answer (score -1):

#### Definitely recommend: [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It could be made a bit more valuable to future readers if you (briefly) explain how to obtain, configure, and use the tool to solve the problem at hand. Thanks!

Comment: `brew install diff-so-fancy` then follow the export suggestions linked in my answer. It was very easy to setup.