# Is there any way to colorize the conflicts in the git output of merge/rebase/patch/am commands?

Tags: terminal, colors, git, output

This is a rebound of [How to colorize output of git?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git)

I want to colorize any conflicts in the git output of merge/rebase/patch/am commands.

```
Applying: CH10: Stub file added with notes copied from video recording lessons.
Applying: TOC: Adding Chapter 10 to the book build.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   book.asciidoc
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging book.asciidoc
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in book.asciidoc
Recorded preimage for 'book.asciidoc'
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 TOC: Adding Chapter 10 to the book build.
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /Users/emmajane/Git/1234000002182/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

It will be very helpful if CONFLICT is in some other color that I can stop easily

Comment: See also [StackOverflow’s “Git color merge/rebase conflicts”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686316/git-color-merge-rebase-conflicts).

Comment: Not really a U&L question; more apt for SO.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Well, it's a question about "Applications packaged in *nix distributions" so I think it's on-topic here. I suspect OP would find more experts on [so], but it's up to OP to pick from all the sites his/her question is on-topic.

Comment: are you looking for a native git solution, or an external (`grep` with color) method?

Comment: Something more concrete from native git. I did not find any color for the conflict errors in the actual git color help pages.

I can try one of the solutions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686316/git-color-merge-rebase-conflicts by @derobert