# How to enable `git gui` in NixOS?

Tags: git, nixos

I've installed [`git` and `tk`](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Git), and I'm able to run `git citool` to display the Git GUI and create a *single* commit, after which the application exits. Unfortunately the `git gui` command itself says

> git: 'gui' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

and so I'm stuck. How do I

1. enable `git gui` as a command to
2. show the Git GUI until I want to exit it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing `git` and `tk` won't work on NixOS because `git` won't be able to *see* tk. Unlike most Linux distributions, NixOS doesn't have a global location (such as `/usr/lib`) for libraries. Instead, executables are modified in such a way that they are able to locate the libraries they need in the Nix store (`/nix/store`).

To use `git gui` install `gitFull` instead of `git`.

Both packages actually come from the same Nix expression, but when using `gitFull` the expression is applied such that it includes support for `git gui`.

Answer (score 1):

In case one uses home-manager / `home.nix`, one needs to set `package = pkgs.gitFull`:

```
  programs.git = {
    enable = true;
    userName = "Firstname Lastname";
    userEmail = "email@example.com";
    package = pkgs.gitFull;
  };
```

Side note: One can also set more options if one wants to:

```
    extraConfig = {
      push = {
        # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/873282
        autoSetupRemote = true;
    
        # Always push to the branch we pulled from
        # See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault for details
        default = "current";
      };

      # Use SVN's ||| also in git - and remove matching lines in the conflict region
      #  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergeconflictStyle for details
      merge = { configStyle = "zdiff3"; };

      # Colors in output
      # Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44297/18033
      color = { ui = "auto"; };
     
      # Sort branches at "git branch -v" by committer date
      branch = { sort = "-committerdate"; };

      # tabs are 4 spaces wide
      gui = { tabsize = 4; };
    };
```